# Can SPF records contain domain name wildcards?

Tags: spf

Part of my SPF record contains:

```
include:google.com
```

I'm still getting soft fail because the actual e-mail is delivered by the following

`Received: from mail-yx0-f172.google.com (mail-yx0-f172.google.com [209.85.213.172`]

Which has a completely different IP from google.com.  However I don't want to put in mail-yx0-f172.google.com because it might be dynamic.  Is there some equivalent of *.google.com that I can use in the record

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No you can't. That is not the correct SPF record, and it is not the correct address of Google's SPF record. Anyone with the control of a reverse DNS domain can make any IP have any name he/she wants, like "google.com", "whitehouse.gov", etc. Allowing reverse matches at all would be very wrong.

The "include" feature of SPF works differently. It does a direct DNS resolution on the given name, and then processes the records that comes from that response. The correct SPF record for Google's e-mail servers is:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

The match is done by IP address from the results returned by a TXT DNS query to `_spf.google.com`. Should Google ever change the IP address of their mail servers, this record should be changed too. As of today, a query to that record returns:

```
~% dig +short txt _spf.google.com
"v=spf1 ip4:216.239.32.0/19 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.249.80.0/20
ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ip4:209.85.128.0/17 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip4:74.125.0.0/16
ip4:64.18.0.0/20 ip4:207.126.144.0/20 ip4:173.194.0.0/16 ?all"
```

Note that the address you are seeing, 209.85.213.172, is included above, in 209.85.128.0/17. So, if your SPF record is configured correctly, it should PASS.

More information on [Google Apps Help](https://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=178723).

Comment: What does the `~` before `all` do? I know `-` (strict) and `+` permissive, but haven't seen that one.

Comment: The `~` signifies soft-fail

Comment: That was a missing piece of information, dealing with SPF records as a newbie for 3 hours already ... Nicely described.